# If someone received a coin or a dollar bill which had particular value as a gift item, would Maaser apply?

Tags: money, maaser-tithes, gifts

According to the opinion than *Maaser* [does not apply](http://dinonline.org/2010/05/14/maaser-from-gifts/) to non monetary gifts, If someone received a coin or a dollar bill which had particular value as a gift item - for example a coin or bill given by a great tzaddik, or a rare coin or bill for a collector - would *Maaser* apply?

**Notes:**

1- This is NOT about whether Maaser of money in general is obligatory or not.

2- This is NOT about whether or not coins or bills of tzadikim have any extra value.

Comment: really interesting question. I'm fairly sure the non-currency value would not apply, but not sure about the currency value. I suspect it would be dependent on a) whether anyone uses it as currency b) what it was given as (i.e. a coin with a face value that's never intended to be spent is probably not, but general-circulation coins with a misprint maybe yes)

Comment: Doesn't ma'aser apply to any asset? I am aware that people give ma'aser on earnings. Do they give ma'ser when getting gifts? E.g. what if someone gives me a car? I'm just curious as to whether your question is specific to any gifts or just those that have "collectors' value"?

Comment: @DanF I wasn't addressing the general question whether maaser is given from gifts. Read the linked article  in the question for more information on that.

Answer (score 1):

Those who hold the opinion than Maaser does not apply to non monetary gifts, reason it by the fact that the **receiver does not intend to use its selling value for resale** but just uses it, as if the giver would explicitly condition the gift by saying "not for resale".

This is very common when parent give their kids very expenive gifts, like cars and do not want to put the burden of the Maaser on them (*I personally got a $30K car gift from my father in law and spoke to R Shlezinger about the $3K Maaser*).

Therefore, if the receiver intends to keep and enjoy the gift, it BECOMES non-monetary and therefore non Maaserable, but if it is a collectible that is intended to be sold, it becomes monetary and Maaserable.

Comment: Sources? [15 char]